# Need little clarification about Neyman-Pearson Lemma

Tags: random-variables, hypothesis-testing

According to my text-book **Neyman-Pearson lemma** says that the most powerful test of size $\alpha$ for testing point hypotheses $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ and  $H_1: \theta=\theta_1$ is a likelihood ratio test of the form

\begin{align*}
\phi(x)= \left\{
         \begin{array}{ll}
          \displaystyle 1, & \quad x > k \\ 
           \gamma, & \quad x = k \\
             0, & \quad x < k             
         \end{array}
     \right.
 \end{align*}

where $l(x)$ is the likelihood ratio

$$l(x)=\frac{f_{\theta_{1}} (x)}{f_{\theta_{0}} (x)}.$$

If $l(x)=k$ with probability zero, then $\gamma=0$ and the *threshold* $k$ is found as

$$\alpha=P_{\theta_{0}}[l(X)>k]=\displaystyle \int_k^\infty f_{\theta_{0}} (l) dl.$$

Where $f_{\theta_{0}} (l)$ is the density function for $l(X)$ under $H_0$.

**Question**
I need to know whether my following understanding is correct.

When it is said that $\alpha=P_{\theta_{0}}[l(X)>k]$, does it mean that **$l(X)$ is now a function of random variable $X$ where $X \sim f_{\theta_{0}}(x)$** and threshold $k$ should be calculated from $1-CDF_L(k)=\alpha$?

Answer (score 0):

$l(X)$ is a function of a random variable so it is a random variable. If you can find the distribution of $l(X)$, then you can calculate the integral as $1-F_l(k)$.

Comment: So, the next question: How $X$ is distributed ?

Comment: It is given to you. Under $H_i$ it is distributed as $F_{\theta_i}$, the distribution corresponding to the density $f_{\theta_i}$.

Comment: I mean, for $l(X)$ which distribution should be taken into account $f_{\theta_0}$ or $f_{\theta_1}$?

Comment: neither of them. Think that $l$ is a function, which is known, that is the ratio of two density functions. And now look at my previous comment for $X$.

Comment: I think, $\alpha=P_{\theta_{0}}[l(X)>k]$ suggests that $X \sim f_{\theta_0}$.

Comment: that is true. What else can be?

Comment: So, to calculate pdf of $l(X)$, $X \sim f_{\theta_0}$ must assumed.

Comment: no assumption it is the fact.